# Django database migration error (sqlite3->postgre)

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, django-migrations

I have created an app using django, now I am trying to use anther database instead of its default which is sqlite3. I have chosen postgres.

When I run the command

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the following erros:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/root/mypro/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
        psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "banners_supercat" does not exist
        LINE 1: ...supercat"."id", "banners_supercat"."english" FROM "banners_s...
                                                                     ^


        The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

        Traceback (most recent call last):
    ....
              File "/root/mypro/banners/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
            from . import views
          File "/root/mypro/banners/views.py", line 13, in <module>
            from .forms import (GoodBaseFormEn, GoodBaseFormFa, CreateSelectField, CreateFormDyn,
          File "/root/mypro/banners/forms.py", line 190, in <module>
            class CreateSearchFormDynEn(forms.Form):
          File "/root/mypro/banners/forms.py", line 191, in CreateSearchFormDynEn
            supercat = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=[('','   ')]+getAllSuperCats(cv.I_EN), label='Category')
          File "/root/mypro/banners/queryfuncs.py", line 59, in getAllSuperCats
            return list(SuperCat.objects.all().values_list('id',('farsi', 'english')[lan]))
          File "/root/mypro/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
            self._fetch_all()
          File "/root/mypro/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
            self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
          File "/root/mypro/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 138, in __iter__
            return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
          File "/root/mypro/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1019, in results_iter
            results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
          File "/root/mypro/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1068, in execute_sql
            cursor.execute(sql, params)
 ...
          File "/root/mypro/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
            raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
          File "/root/mypro/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
        django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "banners_supercat" does not exist
        LINE 1: ...supercat"."id", "banners_supercat"."english" FROM "banners_s...
```

what is the problem and what should I do?

Comment: could you share your models.py ?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

run `python manage.py inspectdb`
it will display your migrated models, compare that with your models.py

make your models.py same as inspectdb result

after that do

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake <migrationfile_number> (eg:0002)
```

after fake migration, change the models.py as before
then do

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

it will solve the migration issue...

Comment: I did the `inspectdb` command but it gave me this:
`# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey has on_delete set to the desired behavior.
#   * Remove managed = False lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from django.db import models`